# Django: Add variable to template tag

Tags: django

I use `{{ order.total_gross|currencynofmt:order.event.currency }}` to display 200.00 and `{{ order.total_gross|currencyfmt:order.event.currency }}` to display $200.00

What's changing is `format=True` or `format=False`. I wonder if there is a way to bring that into one template tag as they are very similar.

register = template.Library()

```
@register.filter
def currencyfmt(amount, currency_iso_code):
    return smallest_currency_unit_converter(
        amount,
        currency_iso_code,
        reverse=True,
        format=True
    )


@register.filter
def currencynofmt(amount, currency_iso_code):
    return smallest_currency_unit_converter(
        amount,
        currency_iso_code,
        reverse=True,
        format=False
    )
```

Comment: You can use a template tag instead. They can take any number of arguments. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=False)
def currencyrepresentation(amount, currency_iso_code, format):
    return smallest_currency_unit_converter(
        amount,
        currency_iso_code,
        reverse=True,
        format=format
    )
```

and in your template:

```
{% currencyrepresentation amount currency_iso_code format as currency_formatted %}
{{currency_formatted}}
```

Comment: Ah that's great. `def currencyrepresentation(amount, currency_iso_code, format=True):`

That would make sure default is True, is that correct?